# Azure policy to restrict VM series allowed in each region

Tags: azure-policy

I need a policy that will restrict certain series in certain regions. So like US East allows A and F series, AU East only allows F and H series VM's. How can this be done in the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done like this:

```
{
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sku.name",
              "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
            }
          },
          {
          "field": "location",
          "equals": "[parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    },
    "parameters": {
      "listOfAllowedSKUs": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Allowed Size SKUs",
          "description": "The list of VM series that can be specified for virtual machines.",
          "strongType": "vmSKUs"
        }
      },
      "listOfAllowedLocations": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Allowed locations",
          "description": "The list of locations where the selected VM's are allowed.",
          "strongType": "location"
        },
          "allowedValues": [
              "australiaeast",
              "eastus",
              "uksouth",
              "westus2",
              "southeastasia"
          ]
        }
      }
}
```